# Assign the vaue of a header fetched from a rest response to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, rest, http-headers

I want to read a header from a rest response and store it in a variable.
Till now I am able to fetch the header from the response. But not able to store it in a variable.

This is how I am posting the request and successfully fetching the header:

```
var options = {
  uri: 'http://xxxyyyxxx.com',
  method: 'POST',
  json: {
     "username": "someUserName",
     "password": "somePassword"
  },
};
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log("AUTHORIZATION=",response.headers['authorization']);
  }
});
```

Now I want to assign the header to a variable.
I tried this way but its not working:

```
var header = response.headers['authorization']; //Code not working
console.log(header); //Code not working
```

Could someone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error? Is this a variable scope issue?

Comment: Not getting any error. I have written the 2 lines of code, which are not working, under if condition only.

Comment: Does the call to response.headers['authorization'] give back a JSON object?

Comment: I doubt. Can you comment out the `if()` so that header is assigned value without checking statusCode or error?

Comment: Voila!! That worked. Thanks man.

Comment: But i wonder how is that if() affecting the assignment?